# How to override default equations? Continued

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I revive this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380792/how-to-override-default-equations) because

1) Michael says the Base and the CustomizedClass are not necessary. I could not figure out how to eliminate them. You basically need a customised model, where you override the equation. How can this be done without these additional constructs Base and CustomizedClass?

2) most importantly - How would the example work for several variables/ equations? Let's say you have 3 equations. How can you override only 1 or 2 of them - without redeclaring the 3rd one?
Or to reformulate the question: How can a model - including all the equations - be redeclared/overridden by a model which redefines only parts of its equations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) you use several modifications: equations(x=1, y=a+b*c, z=u+d+y) or b) you replace an entire class that contains different equations

Comment: For your point 2) you cannot do that, if you have an equation (in an equation section, not a binding Real x=2;) in the base class you cannot override it via extends. You can only replace the entire model one level up but then you need to write *all* equations, repeating some of them. Alternatively you could use if equations and have all the alternative equations in the base class and you only activate them via modifications to if conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much Adrian. Pity for me.

Comment: My actual problem, is that I want to model fluid flows (valves, pumps, vessels, etc.), but have a very hard time to understand how to get flows and streams working. I will open a new question specifically for this issue. Thanks again.